# Deleting an item in the right click menu

Tags: right-click

Some days ago I installed Folder Lock in my computer then I uninstalled it but the item "Lock file with Folder Lock" still remains in the right click menu.
How can it be removed?

Comment: For future reference, this is the "context menu". (May make google searches easier). Also, what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) or [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).